# Add-in for Outlook 2010 does not get installed on Win7 machine that does not have SP1

Tags: plugins, windows-7, vsto, outlook-2010, office-addins

We created an Add-in for Outlook 2010. While it works well on Win7 machine that has SP1 however it doesn't appear in the ribbon on machines that does not have Service Pack 1 installed. There is no error during or after installation just that the add-in goes into Inactive State. Any fix we could do that the add-in works on both the types?

Answer (score 0):

Set the LoadBehaviour of the Addin to 3 .

[image]